# Adjacency list model with CTE and GROUP BY and WITH ROLLUP on Specific Condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table that is hierarchical. I represent it using the Adjacency List.

The following is the query statement that I use:

```
WITH RECURSIVE account_path (root, id, parent_id, name, lvl, `sort`, account_roll_up_id) AS(
   SELECT name AS root, id, parent_id, `name`, 0 lvl, `sort`, account_roll_up_id
   FROM account_type
   WHERE id IN (30, 213)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT cp.root AS root,
          c.id,
          c.parent_id,
          c.name,
          (cp.lvl + 1),
          c.sort,
          c.account_roll_up_id
   FROM account_path AS cp
            JOIN account_type AS c ON cp.id = c.parent_id
)

SELECT MAX(sort)                                                           AS `sort`
     , MIN(root)                                                           AS root
     , MIN(parent_id)                                                      AS parent_id
     , MIN(id)                                                             AS id
     , MIN(account_roll_up_id)                                             AS roll_id
     , MIN(lvl)                                                            AS lvl
     , GROUPING(base.account_roll_up_id, base.id) AS 'grouping_both'
     , IF( GROUPING (base.account_roll_up_id, base.id),
         CONCAT(REPEAT("     ", MIN(lvl)), "=> TOTAL ",UPPER(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT account_roll_up_name)),
               ""),
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT account_name ORDER BY account_roll_up_name)) AS 'rollup_name'
     , SUM(IF(location_id = 1, ending_balance, 0))                         as 'TMS JKT'

FROM (
         SELECT ap.id                                                             AS id
              , MIN(ap.parent_id)                                                 AS parent_id
              , coa.location_id
              , ap.sort
              , MIN(ap.root)                                                      AS root
              , lvl
              , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT location_name)                              AS location_name
              , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(REPEAT("     ", ap.lvl), ap.`name`)) AS account_name
              , COALESCE(
                 IF(SUM(coa.debit) > SUM(coa.credit), SUM(coa.debit) - SUM(coa.credit),
                    SUM(coa.credit) - SUM(coa.debit)),
                 0)                                                               AS ending_balance
              , MIN(account_roll_up_id)                                           AS account_roll_up_id
              , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT aru.name)                                   as account_roll_up_name
         FROM account_path ap
                  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT chart_of_account_id,
                    chart_of_account.name,
                    chart_of_account.location_id,
                    chart_of_account.account_type_id,
                    l.name as location_name,
                    jd.debit,
                    jd.credit,
                    journal.date
             FROM chart_of_account
                      LEFT JOIN journal_detail jd on chart_of_account.id = jd.chart_of_account_id
                      LEFT JOIN journal ON jd.journal_id = journal.id
                      LEFT JOIN location l on chart_of_account.location_id = l.id

             WHERE chart_of_account.header_or_detail = 1
               AND MONTH(journal.date) = 4
               AND YEAR(journal.date) = 2021
         ) AS coa ON coa.account_type_id = ap.id
                  LEFT JOIN account_roll_up AS aru ON aru.id = ap.account_roll_up_id

         GROUP BY ap.id, coa.location_id, ap.sort, ap.lvl
         ORDER BY ap.`sort`, ap.lvl, location_id
     ) AS base

GROUP BY base.account_roll_up_id, base.id
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING rollup_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY MAX(base.sort), GROUPING (base.account_roll_up_id, base.id);
```

```
+------+----------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| sort | root           | parent_id | id   | roll_id | lvl  | grouping_rollup_id | grouping_id | grouping_both | rollup_name                                                                                                                                        | TMS JKT      |
+------+----------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|    1 | AKTIVA         |      NULL |   30 |    NULL |    0 |                  0 |           0 |             0 | AKTIVA                                                                                                                                             |         0.00 |
|    2 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   40 |       2 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Aktiva Lancar                                                                                                                                 |         0.00 |
|    3 | AKTIVA         |        40 |   41 |       2 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Kas & Bank                                                                                                                               |         0.00 |
|    4 | AKTIVA         |        41 |   42 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Kas                                                                                                                                 |   3725000.00 |
|    6 | AKTIVA         |        41 |   44 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Kas Tunai Di Brankas                                                                                                                |  25000000.00 |
|    7 | AKTIVA         |        41 |   46 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Bank                                                                                                                                | 107350000.00 |
|    8 | AKTIVA         |        40 |   47 |       2 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Piutang                                                                                                                                  |         0.00 |
|    9 | AKTIVA         |        47 |   56 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Piutang Penjualan                                                                                                                   |         0.00 |
|   10 | AKTIVA         |        47 |   57 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Piutang Principal                                                                                                                   |         0.00 |
|   23 | AKTIVA         |        40 |   48 |       2 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Biaya Dibayar Di Muka                                                                                                                    |         0.00 |
|   24 | AKTIVA         |        48 |   73 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Pajak Dibayar Di Muka                                                                                                               |         0.00 |
|   25 | AKTIVA         |        48 |   70 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Asuransi Dibayar Di Muka                                                                                                            |         0.00 |
|   28 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   40 |       2 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL AKTIVA LANCAR                                                                                                                        | 136075000.00 |
|   29 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   49 |       3 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Investasi Jangka Panjang                                                                                                                      |         0.00 |
|   30 | AKTIVA         |        49 |  212 |       3 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Saham                                                                                                                                    |         0.00 |
|   30 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   49 |       3 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL INVESTASI JANGKA PANJANG                                                                                                             |         0.00 |
|   31 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   50 |       4 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Aktiva Tetap                                                                                                                                  |         0.00 |
|   32 | AKTIVA         |        50 |   76 |       4 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Tanah                                                                                                                                    | 120000000.00 |
|   33 | AKTIVA         |        50 |   77 |       4 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Gedung & Bangunan                                                                                                                        |         0.00 |
|   50 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   50 |       4 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL AKTIVA TETAP                                                                                                                         | 120000000.00 |
|   51 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   51 |       5 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Aktiva Tidak Berwujud                                                                                                                         |         0.00 |
|   52 | AKTIVA         |        51 |   85 |       5 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Biaya Pra Operasional                                                                                                                    |         0.00 |
|   53 | AKTIVA         |        51 |   86 |       5 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Akumulasi Depresiasi Aktiva Tidak Berwujud                                                                                               |         0.00 |
|   53 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   51 |       5 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL AKTIVA TIDAK BERWUJUD                                                                                                                |         0.00 |
|   54 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   52 |       6 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Aktiva Lainnya                                                                                                                                |         0.00 |
|   55 | AKTIVA         |        52 |   75 |       6 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Deposito / Jaminan                                                                                                                       |         0.00 |
|   55 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   52 |       6 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL AKTIVA LAINNYA                                                                                                                       |         0.00 |
|   56 | HUTANG & MODAL |      NULL |  213 |    NULL |    0 |                  0 |           0 |             0 | HUTANG & MODAL                                                                                                                                     |         0.00 |
|   57 | HUTANG & MODAL |       213 |   88 |    NULL |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Hutang                                                                                                                                        |         0.00 |
|   58 | HUTANG & MODAL |        88 |   89 |       9 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Hutang Jangka Pendek                                                                                                                     |         0.00 |
|   59 | HUTANG & MODAL |        89 |  106 |       9 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Hutang Dagang Lainnya                                                                                                               |         0.00 |
|   60 | HUTANG & MODAL |        89 |   93 |       9 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Hutang SDL                                                                                                                          |         0.00 |
|   71 | HUTANG & MODAL |        88 |   89 |       9 |    2 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |           => TOTAL HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK                                                                                                            |         0.00 |
|   72 | HUTANG & MODAL |        88 |   90 |      10 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Hutang Jangka Panjang                                                                                                                    |         0.00 |
|   73 | HUTANG & MODAL |        90 |  105 |      10 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Hutang Bank                                                                                                                         |         0.00 |
|   73 | HUTANG & MODAL |        88 |   90 |      10 |    2 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |           => TOTAL HUTANG JANGKA PANJANG                                                                                                           |         0.00 |
|   74 | HUTANG & MODAL |       213 |   91 |    NULL |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Modal                                                                                                                                         |         0.00 |
|   75 | HUTANG & MODAL |        91 |  107 |      11 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Modal Saham                                                                                                                              | 500000000.00 |
|   77 | HUTANG & MODAL |        91 |  107 |      11 |    2 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |           => TOTAL MODAL                                                                                                                           | 500000000.00 |
|   77 | AKTIVA         |        30 |   30 |       2 |    0 |                  1 |           1 |             3 | => TOTAL AKTIVA LAINNYA,AKTIVA LANCAR,AKTIVA TETAP,AKTIVA TIDAK BERWUJUD,HUTANG JANGKA PANJANG,HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK,INVESTASI JANGKA PANJANG,MODAL | 756075000.00 |
+------+----------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Please focus on the query result table. If you look closely, you can see that there are two roots (AKTIVA, HUTANG & MODAL).

I want to rollup both data.

So that the final data that we will achieve is as follows.

```
+------+----------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| sort | root                 | parent_id | id   | roll_id | lvl  | grouping_rollup_id | grouping_id | grouping_both | rollup_name                                                                                                                                        | TMS JKT      |
+------+----------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|    1 | AKTIVA               |      NULL |   30 |    NULL |    0 |                  0 |           0 |             0 | AKTIVA                                                                                                                                             |         0.00 |
|    2 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   40 |       2 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Aktiva Lancar                                                                                                                                 |         0.00 |
|    3 | AKTIVA               |        40 |   41 |       2 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Kas & Bank                                                                                                                               |         0.00 |
|    4 | AKTIVA               |        41 |   42 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Kas                                                                                                                                 |   3725000.00 |
|    6 | AKTIVA               |        41 |   44 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Kas Tunai Di Brankas                                                                                                                |  25000000.00 |
|    7 | AKTIVA               |        41 |   46 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Bank                                                                                                                                | 107350000.00 |
|    8 | AKTIVA               |        40 |   47 |       2 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Piutang                                                                                                                                  |         0.00 |
|    9 | AKTIVA               |        47 |   56 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Piutang Penjualan                                                                                                                   |         0.00 |
|   10 | AKTIVA               |        47 |   57 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Piutang Principal                                                                                                                   |         0.00 |
|   23 | AKTIVA               |        40 |   48 |       2 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Biaya Dibayar Di Muka                                                                                                                    |         0.00 |
|   24 | AKTIVA               |        48 |   73 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Pajak Dibayar Di Muka                                                                                                               |         0.00 |
|   25 | AKTIVA               |        48 |   70 |       2 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Asuransi Dibayar Di Muka                                                                                                            |         0.00 |
|   28 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   40 |       2 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL AKTIVA LANCAR                                                                                                                        | 136075000.00 |
|   29 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   49 |       3 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Investasi Jangka Panjang                                                                                                                      |         0.00 |
|   30 | AKTIVA               |        49 |  212 |       3 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Saham                                                                                                                                    |         0.00 |
|   30 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   49 |       3 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL INVESTASI JANGKA PANJANG                                                                                                             |         0.00 |
|   31 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   50 |       4 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Aktiva Tetap                                                                                                                                  |         0.00 |
|   32 | AKTIVA               |        50 |   76 |       4 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Tanah                                                                                                                                    | 120000000.00 |
|   33 | AKTIVA               |        50 |   77 |       4 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Gedung & Bangunan                                                                                                                        |         0.00 |
|   50 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   50 |       4 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL AKTIVA TETAP                                                                                                                         | 120000000.00 |
|   51 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   51 |       5 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Aktiva Tidak Berwujud                                                                                                                         |         0.00 |
|   52 | AKTIVA               |        51 |   85 |       5 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Biaya Pra Operasional                                                                                                                    |         0.00 |
|   53 | AKTIVA               |        51 |   86 |       5 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Akumulasi Depresiasi Aktiva Tidak Berwujud                                                                                               |         0.00 |
|   53 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   51 |       5 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL AKTIVA TIDAK BERWUJUD                                                                                                                |         0.00 |
|   54 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   52 |       6 |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Aktiva Lainnya                                                                                                                                |         0.00 |
|   55 | AKTIVA               |        52 |   75 |       6 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Deposito / Jaminan                                                                                                                       |         0.00 |
|   55 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   52 |       6 |    1 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |      => TOTAL AKTIVA LAINNYA                                                                                                                       |         0.00 |
|      | TOTAL AKTIVA         |           |      |         |      |                    |             |               | TOTAL AKTIVA LANCAR + TOTAL AKTIVA LAINNYA + TOTAL INVESTASI JANGKA PANJANG + TOTAL AKTIVA TETAP + TOTAL AKTIVA TIDAK BERWUJUD+TOTAL AKTIVA LAINNYA| 256075000.00 |
|   56 | HUTANG & MODAL       |      NULL |  213 |    NULL |    0 |                  0 |           0 |             0 | HUTANG & MODAL                                                                                                                                     |         0.00 |
|   57 | HUTANG & MODAL       |       213 |   88 |    NULL |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Hutang                                                                                                                                        |         0.00 |
|   58 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        88 |   89 |       9 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Hutang Jangka Pendek                                                                                                                     |         0.00 |
|   59 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        89 |  106 |       9 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Hutang Dagang Lainnya                                                                                                               |         0.00 |
|   60 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        89 |   93 |       9 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Hutang SDL                                                                                                                          |         0.00 |
|   71 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        88 |   89 |       9 |    2 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |           => TOTAL HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK                                                                                                            |         0.00 |
|   72 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        88 |   90 |      10 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Hutang Jangka Panjang                                                                                                                    |         0.00 |
|   73 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        90 |  105 |      10 |    3 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |                Hutang Bank                                                                                                                         |         0.00 |
|   73 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        88 |   90 |      10 |    2 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |           => TOTAL HUTANG JANGKA PANJANG                                                                                                           |         0.00 |
|   74 | HUTANG & MODAL       |       213 |   91 |    NULL |    1 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |      Modal                                                                                                                                         |         0.00 |
|   75 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        91 |  107 |      11 |    2 |                  0 |           0 |             0 |           Modal Saham                                                                                                                              | 500000000.00 |
|   77 | HUTANG & MODAL       |        91 |  107 |      11 |    2 |                  0 |           1 |             1 |           => TOTAL MODAL                                                                                                                           | 500000000.00 |
|      | TOTAL HUTANG & MODAL |           |      |         |      |                    |             |               | TOTAL HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK + TOTAL HUTANG JANGKA PANJANG  + TOTAL MODAL                                                                            | 500000000.00 |
|   77 | AKTIVA               |        30 |   30 |       2 |    0 |                  1 |           1 |             3 | => TOTAL AKTIVA LAINNYA,AKTIVA LANCAR,AKTIVA TETAP,AKTIVA TIDAK BERWUJUD,HUTANG JANGKA PANJANG,HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK,INVESTASI JANGKA PANJANG,MODAL | 756075000.00 |
+------+----------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Is this possible at the database level? Here is the SQL file if you want to play with it: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bSxEmq7s)

Comment: Please simplify your code to compact adequate model.

Comment: Please use https://pastebin.com/bSxEmq7s to reproduce the table